# What are the visual cognitive abilities of a new born?

Tags: developmental-psychology, vision

We know that a newborn (3 days or less) can mimic facial expressions such as tongue protrusion and head movement. This means that the child can detect faces, segment various parts of face like tongue, associate it with its own tongue and similarly detect its head, determine its position with respect to the shoulders and relate it to its own head.

Am I correct in concluding that a newborn's vision is much more advanced than state of art computer vision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At birth, **visual structures** are fully present yet **immature** in their potentials.

Following are the innate visual abilities of an infant

```
1. detect changes in brightness, 
2. distinguish between stationary and kinetic objects, 
3. follow kinetic objects in their visual fields.
```

However, many of these areas are very poorly developed.

With physical improvements such as

```
1. increased distances between the cornea and retina, 
2. increased pupil dimensions, 
3. strengthened cones and rods
```

an infant's visual ability improves with time.

The **neuro- pathway** and **physical changes** that underlie these **improvements** in vision remains a strong focus in research.

Because of an infant's inability to **verbally** express their visual field, growing research in this field relays heavy on non-verbal cues including

```
an infants perceived ability to detect patterns and visual changes.
```

You may find more details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infant_vision)